# How to keep checkbox checked or unchecked after page refreshed using local-storage?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage

How to keep checkbox checked or unchecked after page refreshed using local-storage in Angularjs?

Here I wrote some code:

```
<ul class="custom-checkbox">
                <li ng-repeat="type in typeoffeatures">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{type.value}}" ng-checked=type.flagset ng-click="toggleSelection1(type.value)" value="{{type.value}}" required/>
                    <label for="{{type.value}}"><div class='custom-chkbox'>
                            <span>{{type.value}}</span>
                        </div></label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**JS Code:**

```
   $scope.typeoffeatures = [{
           value : 'Authentication',
           flagset : true,
       },{
            value : 'Notification',
            flagset : false,
       },{
           value : 'Analytics',
            flagset : true,
       }];
  });
```

[Codepen link here](https://codepen.io/rushijogle/pen/bBMKVZ?editors=1010).

Answer (score 2):

I've made a few adjustments to your codepen:

- added `ng-model` to the checkboxes
- changed `ng-click` to `ng-change` (more reliable)
- added `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to represent true and false as strings

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{type.value}}" ng-model="type.flagset" 
         ng-change="saveField(type.value, type.flagset)"
         ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'" required/>
  ```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOeKjj?editors=1010